# Check if a python program exited with an exception

Tags: python

I'm doing some processing in a `__del__()` destructor of a Python object that I don't want to happen if the program exited via exception. Is there a way to check from `__del__()` if I'm in the middle of normal exit or exception unwinding?

Alternatively is there some way to check for the same condition in the `atexit` function?

Comment: Why would you need to know that? What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve here? You'd normally detect if the resources still need cleaning up, regardless of what else is happening.

Comment: My use case is an object that that iterates over a stream of data and caches it to disk (as json). If the program was killed, I do not want to use the cache next time, this is why i use `__del__()` to touch a 'cache_complete_ok' file. The problem is if the program was killed with C-c, KeyBoard exception does not prevent __del__() from touching 'cache_complete_ok', even though the processing was not finished.

Comment: This is a good candidate for an object with a close() method or perhaps a context manager. I use context managers for this type of thing regularly. The context exit will tell you whether you are in an exception.

Comment: Then use a context manager and in the `__exit__` only mark the cache as reusable if no exceptions occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a `__del__` for this. The [`__del__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) is not even guaranteed to be called:

> It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

Instead, manage the cache with a [Context Manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) and only mark the cache as reusable when the [`__exit__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) is called with the `exc_type` set to `None`.